# Do attack speed/movement debuff items draw turret aggro when their passive is triggered by an enemy champion?

Tags: league-of-legends

So I know the question is a bit subjective however it makes sense soon. So here is a small example:

So we're about to close the game and I am taking down the enemy top
 lane's turret, while my team takes down mid.

The enemy Pantheon shows up and I ignore him to focus the turret. I do
 not have any aura items, only my **Warden's mail**. There were other
 minions ahead of me all attacking the turret at this time as well.
 Pantheon uses his <kbd>Q</kbd> <kbd>W</kbd> <kbd>E</kbd> combo and it
 does no damage so I keep ignoring him.

Now **suddenly the turret starts attacking me**, so I kill him then
 back off.

Now I was not really paying attention to him because of how little
 damage he was doing, so I am not sure if he used a basic attack, which
 would have slowed his attack speed due to Warden's Mail.

---

My question is do debuffing items like **Warden's Mail** and **Randuin's Omen** that are triggered by the enemy cause towers to aggro you when their passive effect is activated?

---

After reviewing the replay I noticed that pantheon's e Had cleared the melee minions.

Comment: Could it be that Panth's e killed your remaining minions leaving you the only available target for the turret?

Comment: +1 interesting question.  I can't wait to see the answer.  Personally, I don't know, but I DO know that damage items like Thorn Mail DO agro the turret when they damage the enemy FWIW.

Comment: it sounds like you were the only remaining target or you accidentally hit him during his faceroll

Comment: I believe NOT, since `FEAR` and `EXHAUSTION` doesn't pull turret aggro

Comment: @jonathan Drapeau: Well I was paying close attention to the minion wave and he lost his lane terribly cause i ganked him like three times so he did not have enough damage to wipe the minions and if it were that I mean I would have mentioned it though i do understand what you mean I will look for the reply and update the question. However I had been shoving that lane for about two  waves there was also a cannon minion and some melee and casters with me before and after I killed him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: **No! Aura effects and CC don't cause the turret to aggro you if they don't deal any damage**

Let me explain how turrets work. A turret has an Attack priority which is as follows:

- Super Minions
- Cannon Minions/Monsters
- Champion Pets (Shaco Boxes, Morde Clone etc)
- Meele Minions
- Caster Minions
- Champions

Yes I know the Wiki site says something else when it comes to the order but from personal experience (I often play shaco as a splitpusher) I'm 99% sure it's in this order. I gotta try It out some day in detail and maybe post a video.

Now this is the order in which turrets will attack you. If A target dies or resets aggro the turret will switch to the highest priority target it can find.

There are only 3 Ways to draw turret aggro as a champion:

- Standing in turret range when there is no other target
- Dealing Direct damage to an enemy champion within range of the turret
- Dealing damage via a DOT, Pet or Trap to an enemy champion within turret range.

Note the **Within Turret Range** factor here. If you play Nidalee and you are standing right next to an enemy turret with your minions around, you can toss a spear at an enemy champion that is standing out of turret range and you will **not** draw aggro from it, despite the fact you damaged him.

Also **Every source of damage counts**. People often forget that effects like Sunfire Cape or Thornmail will also get the turret to focus you.

Now as a Final word: If you don't deal any damage you won't draw turret aggro (CC like Nasus slow, Fiddle Fear etc are safe to use under a turret) but don't forget about the "Hidden damage" like Sunfire, Thornmail or Redbuff.

Comment: Wow dude thanks a lot I will keep this in mind(shaco main:D)

Comment: But what about Zil's bombs? Placing one on someone's head does 0 damage, yet it draws aggro.

Comment: @hammythepig That's not true. Zilean Bombs deal 1 True damage every second before it explodes.

Comment: Ah I did not know this! Good to know thanks (:

Comment: @Jutschge from wiki "A ticking bomb does not grant an assist if the target dies before it explodes." so is it false? Also it doesn't mention anywhere about true dmg.

Answer (score 2):

> A turret will prioritize an enemy champion if that champion deals
>   damage to an allied champion who is within the tower's range. Damage
>   dealt can come from any source (pet, aura, item, etc.) in order for a
>   champion to be targeted. Additionally, turrets will target an enemy
>   champion if no other valid target is within range. Turrets will not
>   attack an enemy champion who uses a non-damaging spell (ex.  Karthus's
>   Wall of Pain). A spell or attack that is blocked (by a spell shield or
>   ability effect) and deals no damage will still draw turret aggro.

***SOURCE*** [LoL Turrets](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Turret)

The key word here is damage. Really simply, you must take away health from your opponent WITHIN turret range. Items like Thornmail or Sunfire Cape do damage to your opponents health, and WILL draw turret aggro. Items like WardensMail and Frozen Heart don't damage your opponent, only decrease their stats and WILL NOT draw turret aggro.

Comment: So basically because casters and cannon were behind me and he had cleared the melee I was focused even though I was not attacking him because I was closer than the other minions I was focused:/ damn that sucks but makes sense

Comment: @Broken_Code It may have been close, but League can sometimes be a game of milliseconds, good or bad. It was a good question and looking closer into why things happen is what can make you a much better player than others.